# Solving an Inhomogeneous Boundary Value Problem Using Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

**Question:**

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a given function with $a,b\in\mathbb{R},b\ne0$. Prove that the general solution to the equation $au_x+bu_y=f(x,y)$ is given by
> $u(x,y)=(a^2+b^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{L} f \mathrm{d}s+g(bx-ay)$, where where $g$ is an arbitrary (differentiable) function and $L$ is a characteristic line segment
> containing $(x,y)$. Note $s$ is arc length in the above line integral. Hence, build on your answer to solve the equation $au_x+bu_y=x+y$, with $u(x,0)=e^x$

**My attempt:**

The characteristics satisfy $x'(t)=a, y'(t)=b$.

Therefore, the parametric form of the characteristics is

$\mathbb{r}(t)=(x_0+at, y_0+bt)$.

Since $u$ is constant along its characteristics, we have that $\frac{d}{dt}(u(x_0+at,y_0+bt))=f(x_0+at,y_0+bt) \implies u(x_0+at, y_0+bt)=\int_{0}^{t}f(x_0+aq,y_0+bq)dq+u(x_0,y_0)$

If we make the change of variables to arclength, we find that

$\frac{ds}{dq}=|\frac{dr}{dq}|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies dq=\frac{ds}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\implies q = \frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

Inserting this back into our integral gives us that

$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\int_{0}^{s}f(x_0+a\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},y_0+b\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})ds+g(bx-ay)$, where the constant $u(x_0,y_0)$ was absorbed into the homogeneous solution $g(bx-ay)$

I'm unsure how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use your result to solve the equation $au_x+bu_y=x+y$, with $u(x,0)=e^x$. In this case, $f(x,y)=x+y$, so
\begin{align}
u-g(bx-ay)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\int_{0}^{s}f\!\left(x_0+a\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},y_0+b\frac{s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)ds \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\int_{0}^{s}\left(x_0+y_0+\frac{(a+b)s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)ds \\
&=\frac{(x_0+y_0)s}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{(a+b)s^2}{2(a^2+b^2)}
=(x_0+y_0)t+\frac{1}{2}(a+b)t^2. \tag{1}
\end{align}
The boundary condition $u(x,0)=e^x$ implies $y_0=0$. Then, solving the characteristics $(x,y)=(x_0+at, bt)$ for $t$ and $x_0$, we obtain
$$
(t, x_0)=\left(\frac{y}{b}, x-\frac{ay}{b}\right). \tag{2}
$$
Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$, we get
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{xy}{b}+(b-a)\frac{y^2}{2b^2}+g(bx-ay). \tag{3}
$$
To determine $g$, we again use the condition $u(x,0)=e^x$:
$$
g(bx)=e^x \implies g(\xi)=e^{\xi/b}. \tag{4}
$$
Plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$, we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{xy}{b}+(b-a)\frac{y^2}{2b^2}+\exp\left(x-\frac{ay}{b}\right). \tag{5}
$$